# How to use google/api/annotations.proto with Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a problem with `proto` file in my project
I had import in my proto file:

```
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
```

I am getting following error when building the project.

```
Import "google/api/annotations.proto" was not found or had errors.
```

How can I use this import in my project? Should I add something to my build.gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On non-Android, you could add this dependency to your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.12.0'
```

However, Android uses Protobuf "Lite" instead of full Protobuf and there's not a pre-generated library with Lite for this proto. There is [an open issue about this](https://github.com/googleapis/gapic-generator/issues/1805).

However, a workaround discussed for the [well-known protos](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/1889#issuecomment-261684149) can be used here as well. Namely, use a `protobuf` dependency instead of a `compile` dependency. This will generate the code as part of your build.

```
protobuf 'com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.12.0'
```

Unfortunately, this solution only really works for applications. If two libraries use this "solution" they must never be included into the same application as they will have duplicated (and potentially have different versions of) the generated classes.

Comment: Adding 
    protobuf 'com.google.api.grpc:googleapis-common-protos:0.0.3'
solved my problem

Comment: Does proto-google-common-protos not work for you? googleapis-common-protos is defunct and doesn't receive any updates. [It's repo](https://github.com/googleapis/api-common-protos) suggests proto-google-common-protos.

Comment: proto-google-common-protos is working. I think your solution is even better.